# Dojo XHR treats 200 OK as error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, dojo

I use Dojo **xhr** to post some data to an ASP.NET MVC controller:

```
xhr.post("/MyController", {
       handleAs: "json",
       data: {
          contentIdentifier: 'abc123',
          language: 'en'
        }
     }).then(function (response) {
         console.log('Success.');
     }, function (err) {
         console.error(err);
     });
```

The controller returns a **plain text** result, and I can see the response is indeed **200 OK** from the server.

However, the error handler is always triggered.

When outputting **err** to the console I get something like:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token S
message: "Unexpected token S"
response: { 
   options: TMP
   status: 200
   text: "Successfully pushed content to 1 instance(s)."
```

It seems to me the error is because it cannot parse the plain text response as JSON? I.e. the first "S" in the word "Successfully" is what's breaking **xhr**?

The content type for the response is **text/plain**

Comment: Perhaps I can specify that only the request should be handled as JSON, not the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh.

The **handleAs** argument according to the Dojo docs:

*The content handler to process the **response** payload with.*

In other words, setting **handleAs** to **"text"** solved the problem.